# android SQLite query() 'DRY RUN'

Tags: android, sqlite

Here's some basic code:

```
where(); // Generates "flag0 = 'R' AND (flag211 & 1) == 1"
return database.query( RT, minColumns(), where(), null, null, null, orderby() );
```

In my app the where() method can return a column name that does not exist for several 'good' reasons:
(a) The method is complex and I am only human
(b) The method returns a value directly typed by the user.

In either event, the application crashes as expected:

```
SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: flag211
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
```

How may the query (or even just the validity of the WHERE clause) be validated prior to issuance?

OR How may the exception be trapped and handled nicely?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have researched, there is no SQLite 'dry run' facility per se.

But SQLite query() does throw an Exception that can be trapped, despite a lack of glaringly obvious documentation.

In my question I made it clear that a 'no such column' event was to be considered normal.

If you are running query() in background here is a tested method of trapping the event AND politely notifying the user.

```
public Cursor gimme(Activity A, String where, String orderby, String subFilter) {
    try {return database.query(WAYPOINT, stdColumnsW(subFilter), where, null, null, null, orderby);}
    catch (Exception e) { runToast(e.getMessage(), A); return null; }
}

// 'Toast' does not run in background thread!
private void runToast (String bigMsg, Activity A) {
    // e.g. no such column: flag211 (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, ... ... ...
    int comma = bigMsg.indexOf(",");
    if (comma < 0)  comma = (int)Math.min(50D, (double)bigMsg.length() );
    final String msg = bigMsg.substring(0, comma);
    A.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {Toast.makeText(ctx, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();});
    }
```

Thanks to @Catluc for the useful tip.